# How can I perform accent insensitive searches in CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I'm having a problem when performing searches in my database. My table holds the following record:

```
id : 5
Name : NicolÃ¡s
created : 2015-12-15 13:08:22
modified : 2015-12-15 13:08:22
```

In one of my duties I do a search based on what the user enters:

```
$replaceConditionsInBD = "CONVERT( CAST( UPPER(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(InscripcionesAtributo.valor, ',',''), '.',''), '-',''))) AS BINARY) USING utf8) LIKE";
$condition = '%'.$valor.'%';
$participantes = $this->Participante->Inscripcion->InscripcionesAtributo->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        $replaceConditionsInBD => $condition,
    ),
    'group'=> array('InscripcionesAtributo.inscripcion_id'),
    'fields'=> array('Inscripcion.id'),
    'contain'=> array('Inscripcion.evento_id = '.$this->eventoID)));
```

If I perform a search with an accent, for example the name `Nicolás`, it returns no results. However, if I search for `Nicolas` (without the accent), the record is found.

What I need is to be able to perform an accent insensitive search. This should be applicable to other foreign characters such as the letter `Ñ`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this, but perhaps the easiest is to change the collation of your table to `utf8_general_ci`:

```
ALTER TABLE inscripciones_atributos COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

This will allow you to conduct case-insensitive and accent-insensitive searches, plus other character equivalences, as depicted in:

- [Collation chart for utf8_general_ci, European alphabets](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_general_ci.european.html)

Make sure that the records are UTF8 encoded.